# How to work out $-1 \bmod 7$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

What is the working out for $-1 \bmod 7$?

I can do it if the numbers are positive just the negative throws me off.

Comment: simply add $7$ : $$-1 \equiv  -1+7 \pmod 7$$

Comment: I was making a stupid mistake.

To work out $-1(mod7)$
It simply is long divison
therefore,
how many times does 7 divide in -1? = -7
then -1 take away -7 = 6
Therefore $-1(mod7) =6$

Comment: Since $7\equiv 0 \pmod 7$, you can add/subtract any number of $7$'s.  Btw, $-1$ is friendlier than $6$ for reduction. May I know why you want to work with $6$ instead of $-1$ ? :)

Answer (score 1):

In mod 7, you can add 7 without changing the value

$$-1\equiv-1+7\pmod7$$

Answer (score 0):

The "mod 7" operation means "how many *more* is this number from the next smallest multiple of $7$"? The next smallest multiple of $7$ below $-1$ is $-7$, and $-1$ is $6$ more than that.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the same as with positive numbers, for example you know
$$
4\equiv_{7}11
$$

this is because 
$$
11-7=4
$$

You use the fact that reducing $7$ still leaves you with a congruent
number.

But we can write 
$$
4+7=11
$$

to see that adding $7$ doesn't change it either so 
$$
-1+7\equiv_{7}6
$$

To be more general two numbers $a,b$ are equivalent mod $n$ if and
only if
$$
a-b=kn
$$

for some integer $k$, we wrote it as 
$$
a=b+kn
$$

for $a=-1,b=6,k=-1,n=7$

Answer (score 0):

To compute $x \bmod 7$, recall that if $x$ is positive we keep subtracting 7 from $x$ until we get a number between 0 and 6.  If $x$ is negative we keep adding 7 to $x$ until we get a number between 0 and 6. Thus $-1 \equiv -1+7=6 \bmod 7$.

Answer (score 0):

Well $a \mod b = c$ if there exists a number $n \in \mathbb Z $ such that $bn + c = a$ and $c \in [0, b)$. To answer your question:
$$
-1 \mod 7 = 6
$$

Why? Because for $n=-1, \quad 7 (-1)+6=-1$.

I'm guessing the confusion was whether you should think of $-1$ as $7 (-1)+6=-1$ or as $7 \times 0-1=-1$, but if you always keep in mind that the mod operator can only yield a value between $0$ and the divisor, you will always end up with the correct answer.